# Can't use React.findDOMNode function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason, I'm not able to use React.findDOMNode function. Browser complains about type error, saying React.findDOMNode is not a function. This is the code where this happens:

```js
var React = require('react');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var Car = require('models/car');
var NewCarForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var brand = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.brand).value.trim();
   ...
    this.props.handleNewCar(new Car({brand: brand, model:model,   name:name, kmTraveled:odometer, litresSpent:litres}));
    return;
  },
  render: function() {
    console.log("Inside NewCarForm");
    return (
      <form className="contentSection" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Car Brand" ref="brand" />
       ...
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});
module.exports = NewCarForm;
```

This is the only module where I try to use this function. The rest of React works fine, so I have no idea what could be the problem here.

Comment: try printing out "React" and "React.version" to make sure you're not pulling in multiple versions of react, because there's no other real reason why you wouldn't have it.

Comment: Use ReactDOM.findDOMNode as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031516/reactjs-finddomnode-and-getdomnode-are-not-functions/33031619#33031619).

Answer (score 39):

In React 15 (and possibly some earlier versions, I'm not sure) you don't need `findDOMNode` to use refs at all:

```
this.refs.brand.value
```

is sufficient.

Comment: Perfect Bravo!!

Comment: This should be the accepted... since things have changed

Comment: may hold true for a plain html form elememt , but is still required if the ref if used inside a React Component

Answer (score 14):

`React.findDOMNode(component)` was introduced in React `0.13.0` as a replacement for `component.getDOMNode()`.

Make sure that you have React `0.13.1` installed. If you're using npm, you can run `npm view react version` to check which version of React is currently installed.

Comment: React version is 0.13.1. I will try the getDOMNode() function however.

Answer (score 5):

The `findDOMNode` method has moved from `react` module to the `react-dom` module.

So you have import or require the ReactDOM from `react-dom` module then replace

```
var brand = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.brand).value.trim();
```

With

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var brand = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.brand).value.trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would have commented on @romkyns answer but i don't have the rep.

So, I have been following a tutorial:

https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/15/react-js-and-spring-data-rest-part-2-hypermedia

By changing the content from the newest version of the project on github. There was an error both in the code that relates to the answer I also voted up, but realized there was a mistake.

So you must replace `React.findDOMNode` by `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` and not by deleting `findDOMNode` as you stated.

I am not sure if this is due to a new version of Reactjs but this gave me the awaited result.

Comment: Woops, I did not see the comment from @upg