# ReactJS findDOMNode and getDOMNode are not functions

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm building a web-app with ReactJS and Flux and I'm trying to get the node of my current div using the method **findDOMNode**  and I get the next error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: React.findDOMNode is not a function
```

So, I tried to use **getDOMNode** and I get the very same error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: React.getDOMNode is not a function
```

I'm using npm to build the JS, the code where I use these methods:

```
var React = require('react');
var stores = require('../stores');
var MessagesUserContainer = require('./messageusercontainer');
var ChatStore = stores.ChatStore;
var owner = stores.getOwner();

var MessagesList = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {'muc': []};
    },
    componentDidUpdate: function(){
        var node = React.findDOMNode(this); //Error here
        node.scrollTop = node.scrollHeight;
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
                <div className="chatScroll">
                    {this.state.muc}
                </div>
            )
    }
});

module.exports = MessagesList;
```

**ReactJS verion: 0.14.0**

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the answers, the DOM library as of v0.14.0  is out of the React core, so I made a few changes to my code:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var stores = require('../stores');
var MessagesUserContainer = require('./messageusercontainer');
var ChatStore = stores.ChatStore;
var owner = stores.getOwner();

var MessagesList = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {'muc': []};
    },
    componentDidUpdate: function(){
        var node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        node.scrollTop = node.scrollHeight;
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
                <div className="chatScroll">
                    {this.state.muc}
                </div>
            )
    }
});

module.exports = MessagesList;
```

But I got another problem:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findDOMNode was called on an unmounted component.
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Changed in latest React:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode

It is in the `react-dom` package.  Note that ReactDOMServer has also been moved into another package.  Probably in preparation for React related platform-specific APIs (such as React native).

To import/ require the package:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

or

```
 var ReactDOM = require('react-dom').
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know they created a new package.

Comment: Help man, now I got this error: Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findDOMNode was called on an unmounted component.

Comment: Perhaps `ReactDOM.render`?

Comment: It might be better to separate it into another question (with a link).  This question has gotten a little too cluttered.

Comment: Also check your code and see if you are using "React.render" anywhere.  I suspect you are using `React.render(<component/>,el)` somewhere.  `render()` has been moved to `ReactDOM`

Comment: I'd like to emphasize that the first word is ReactDOM instead of React. I was only focusing on the function name, and didn't notice that the package name is the one which was changed.

Comment: Not working for me like all other mid level methodology , i got TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'react_dom_1.default.findDOMNode') , TS no logs err msg.

Comment: Doesn't allow you to set the node like getDomNode

Answer (score 3):

In react `v0.14` DOM library has been moved from React.js itself. There are some BC changes, but if you wrote your code in a proper way then changes won't be painful. Please read here for full overview: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/#major-changes

Answer (score 0):

As of React 18, `ReactDOM` should be imported from `react-dom/client` while the `findDOMNode` export is considered deprecated and still exported from `react-dom`.

Therefore:

```js
import {findDOMNode} from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
```

Update: Adding [`findDOMNode` documentation link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode)