# Enzyme - How to access and set <input> value?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

I'm confused about how to access `<input>` value when using `mount`. Here's what I've got as my test:

```
  it('cancels changes when user presses esc', done => {
    const wrapper = mount(<EditableText defaultValue="Hello" />);
    const input = wrapper.find('input');

    console.log(input.render().attr('value'));
    input.simulate('focus');
    done();
  });
```

The console prints out `undefined`. But if I slightly modify the code, it works:

```
  it('cancels changes when user presses esc', done => {
    const wrapper = render(<EditableText defaultValue="Hello" />);
    const input = wrapper.find('input');

    console.log(input.val());
    input.simulate('focus');
    done();
  });
```

Except, of course, the `input.simulate` line fails since I'm using `render` now. I need both to work properly. How do I fix this?

**EDIT**:

I should mention, `<EditableText />` is not a controlled component. But when I pass `defaultValue` into `<input />`, it seems to set the value. The second code block above does print out the value, and likewise if I inspect the input element in Chrome and type `$0.value` in the console, it shows the expected value.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Got it. (updated/improved version)

```
  it('cancels changes when user presses esc', done => {
    const wrapper = mount(<EditableText defaultValue="Hello" />);
    const input = wrapper.find('input');

    input.simulate('focus');
    input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Changed' } });
    input.simulate('keyDown', {
      which: 27,
      target: {
        blur() {
          // Needed since <EditableText /> calls target.blur()
          input.simulate('blur');
        },
      },
    });
    expect(input.get(0).value).to.equal('Hello');

    done();
  });
```

Comment: Curious how this works for you.  We're using PhantomJS and `mount()` does not insert components into the DOM.  So, they can't receive focus.  We have to add a DOM element and use the `context` option for `mount()`

Comment: @Pre101 I actually started using Jest instead of Enzyme. Highly recommended!

Comment: @ffxsam : input.get(0).value always displays "undefined"

Comment: @Siddharth_Vyas try `input.prop('value')`

Answer (score 122):

I think what you want is:

```
input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Hello' } })
```

[Here's my source](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/76#issuecomment-189606849).

You shouldn't need to use `render()` anywhere to set the value. And just FYI, you are using two different `render()`'s. The one in your first code block is from Enzyme, and is a method on the wraper object `mount` and `find` give you. The second one, though it's not 100% clear, is probably the one from `react-dom`. If you're using Enzyme, just use `shallow` or `mount` as appropriate and there's no need for `render` from `react-dom`.

Comment: The `input.render()` is not `react-dom` render. It's this: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/render.html

Comment: Also, `shallow()` doesn't work for some reason.. the `focus` event triggers a method which tries to reference `this.refs.input`, which fails. But when I swap out `shallow` for `mount`, it works as expected. Mostly.. (one more issue with simulating ESC key)

Comment: I should have been more clear. I meant the render that looks like `render(<EditableText defaultValue="Hello" />)`. I think your use case is more specialized than I thought; I see it deals note just with setting the input value but with focus and "canceling changes". It would be great if you could create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/).

Comment: Hi, I got issue with default values such as `this.state = {inputNum: 10};`, and the **Received** will always be 1 though the **Expected** is 100 as set in `input.simulate('change', { target: { value: '100' } })`. Could anyone please help?

Comment: @nambk It'd be best to ask a new question. Perhaps it has something to do with the quotes around the `'100'`. I'm not sure about the discrepancy with 10 and 1.

Answer (score 52):

With **Enzyme 3**, if you need to change an input value but don't need to fire the `onChange` function you can just do this (`node` property [has been removed](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.html#private-properties-and-methods-have-been-removed)):

`wrapper.find('input').instance().value = "foo";`

You can use `wrapper.find('input').simulate("change", { target: { value: "foo" }})` to invoke `onChange` if you have a prop for that (ie, for controlled components).

Comment: `NOTE: can only be called on a wrapper instance that is also the root instance.` - from the docs at http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html

Comment: `instance()` can be called on any child wrapper if it was rendered via `mount`.

Comment: By the way, if you are using MUI it's the same, whith TextFields Select and more (you shoud call the "Native" elements and not the MUI ones)

Answer (score 23):

So lots of different opinions here. The only thing that worked for me was none of the above, it was using `input.props().value`. I hope that helps.

Comment: This is the only answer which allowed me to interrogate the input's value.

Comment: Of note, you can also use: `input.prop('value')` if you know the name of your prop key.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using react with TypeScript and the following worked for me

```
wrapper.find('input').getDOMNode<HTMLInputElement>().value = 'Hello';
wrapper.find('input').simulate('change');
```

Setting the value directly

```
wrapper.find('input').instance().value = 'Hello'`
```

was causing me a compile warning.

Comment: I get getDOMNode() is not a function: this was updated in recent React: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031516/reactjs-finddomnode-and-getdomnode-are-not-functions

Comment: Joseph, simulate function is not updating/changing the input value. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

I am using create-react-app which comes with jest by default and enzyme 2.7.0.

This worked for me:

```
const wrapper = mount(<EditableText defaultValue="Hello" />);
const input = wrapper.find('input')[index]; // where index is the position of the input field of interest
input.node.value = 'Change';
input.simulate('change', input);
done();
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the above worked for me. This is what worked for me on Enzyme ^3.1.1:

```
input.instance().props.onChange(({ target: { value: '19:00' } }));
```

Here is the rest of the code for context:

```
const fakeHandleChangeValues = jest.fn();
  const fakeErrors = {
    errors: [{
      timePeriod: opHoursData[0].timePeriod,
      values: [{
        errorIndex: 2,
        errorTime: '19:00',
      }],
    }],
    state: true,
  };
const wrapper = mount(<AccessibleUI
    handleChangeValues={fakeHandleChangeValues}
    opHoursData={opHoursData}
    translations={translationsForRendering}
  />);
const input = wrapper.find('#input-2').at(0);
input.instance().props.onChange(({ target: { value: '19:00' } }));
expect(wrapper.state().error).toEqual(fakeErrors);
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is struggling, I found the following working for me

```
const wrapper = mount(<NewTask {...props} />); // component under test
const textField = wrapper.find(TextField);

textField.props().onChange({ target: { value: 'New Task 2' } })
textField.simulate('change');
// wrapper.update() didn't work for me, need to find element again

console.log(wrapper.find(TextField).props()); // New Task 2
```

It seems that you need to define what happens in the change event first and then simulate it (instead of simulating the change event with data)

Comment: This worked for me. Although I had to put onChange event in act().

Answer (score 2):

This works for me using enzyme 2.4.1:

```
const wrapper = mount(<EditableText defaultValue="Hello" />);
const input = wrapper.find('input');

console.log(input.node.value);
```

Comment: When I started using Jest/enzyme I would often `console.log` an object and dig through (sub-)properties to get what I needed. Doing so, I often ended up using `.node` in some form, like you have. However, I don't recall seeing `.node` being mentioned in any of the official documentation, suggesting it could change/break between releases as it's not officially part of the publically-advertised API. Also, there often seem to be alternatives. e.g. `input.node.value` === `input.get(0).value`. So, `.node` might work, and I suspect that sometimes it will provide a good hack, but use with caution.

Comment: This is no longer a public method.

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions above worked for me because I was using Formik and I needed to mark the field "touched" along with changing the field value. Following code worked for me.

```
const emailField = orderPageWrapper.find('input[name="email"]')

emailField.simulate('focus')
emailField.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test@example.com', name: 'email' } })
emailField.simulate('blur')
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was using ref callbacks,

```
  <input id="usuario" className="form-control" placeholder="Usuario"
                                                       name="usuario" type="usuario"
                                                       onKeyUp={this._validateMail.bind(this)}
                                                       onChange={()=> this._validateMail()}
                                                       ref={(val) =>{ this._username = val}}
                                                    >
```

To obtain the value.
So enzyme will not change the value of this._username.

So i had to:

```
login.node._username.value = "mario@com.com";
    user.simulate('change');
    expect(login.state('mailValid')).toBe(true);
```

To be able to set the value then call change . And then assert.

Answer (score 1):

here is my code..

```
const input = MobileNumberComponent.find('input')
// when
input.props().onChange({target: {
   id: 'mobile-no',
   value: '1234567900'
}});
MobileNumberComponent.update()
const Footer = (loginComponent.find('Footer'))
expect(Footer.find('Buttons').props().disabled).equals(false)
```

I have update my DOM with `componentname.update()`
And then checking submit button validation(disable/enable) with length 10 digit.

Answer (score 1):

I solved in a very simple way:

1. **Set the value from props**:

```
  const wrapper: ShallowWrapper = shallow(<ProfileViewClass name: 'Sample Name' />);
```

2. **Html code**:

```
  <input type='text' defaultValue={props.name} className='edituser-name' />
```

3. **Access the attribute** from `wrapper.find(element).props().attribute-name`:

```
  it('should render user name', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.edituser-name').props().defaultValue).toContain(props.name);
  });
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
let wrapped = mount(<Component />);
expect(wrapped.find("input").get(0).props.value).toEqual("something");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer doesn't suit for this question. But i had a problem that  value for field during testing wasn't changing and tested logic wasn't fired. In my case problem was that callback and value were pass as parameters for component. And just this simple fix helped me to trigger inner logic in tested component:

```
rendered.setProps({ zipCode: '1234567' });
```

Answer (score -1):

I use Wrapper's setValue[https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setvalue-value] method to set  value.

```
inputA = wrapper.findAll('input').at(0)
inputA.setValue('123456')
```

Answer (score -1):

`.simulate()` doesn't work for me somehow, I got it working with just accessing the `node.value` without needing to call `.simulate()`; in your case:

```
const wrapper = mount(<EditableText defaultValue="Hello" />);
const input = wrapper.find('input').at(0);

// Get the value
console.log(input.node.value); // Hello

// Set the value
input.node.value = 'new value';

// Get the value
console.log(input.node.value); // new value
```

Hope this helps for others!

Comment: Throws

```
Attempted to access ReactWrapper::node, which was previously a private property on
            Enzyme ReactWrapper instances, but is no longer and should not be relied upon.
            Consider using the getElement() method instead.
```

Comment: @DaviLima for the newer version of Enzyme, instead of `.node` you should use `.instance()` or `.getDOMNode()`, depends if you used the result as a ReactElement or DOMComponent.