# How do you generate a blur or onBlur event in Enzyme?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, frontend, enzyme

I've tried:

```
input.simulate('blur');
```

and

```
input.simulate('onBlur');
```

None of these work. Is this even available in Enzyme (I'm using version 2.4.1).

Comment: I've used `simulate('blur');` before and it works just fine.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`input.simulate('focus')`, `input.simulate('change')` and `input.simulate('blur')` should work. Check if your **input** is actually a node declared as `_wrapper.find('input')` and exists. Secondly, there's another question similar to this one: [Enzyme - How to access and set <input> value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219772/enzyme-how-to-access-and-set-input-value)
And finally if you [check the source code](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/4d1517ab01c01011d7e7d1b4e9ae4201cd23268d/src/ReactWrapper.jsx#L497) of the [ReactWrapper component](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/4d1517ab01c01011d7e7d1b4e9ae4201cd23268d/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.md) then you will find that it uses [all events that React can recognize](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#supported-events). So the error is somewhere in your code.