# Test setting text value with React and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme

How do you set the text of a text input and then test it's value with React / Enzyme?

```
const input = wrapper.find('#my-input');

input.simulate('change',
  { target: { value: 'abc' } }
);

const val = input.node.value;

//val is ''
```

All the [solutions here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/76) appear not to work..

Comment: It appears that you need to use `mount` for it to work properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enzyme - How to access and set <input> value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219772/enzyme-how-to-access-and-set-input-value)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To really understand what's happening in your code it would be useful to see your component code (specifically your `onChange` handler.

However, in regards to the following code:

```
input.simulate('change', {target: {value: 'abc'}});
```

This won't actually change the value of your `<input />` element, instead it just causes your `onChange` function to be run and be provided an event object that looks like `{target: {value: 'abc'}}`.

The idea is that your `onChange` function would update your state or store, so triggering this function should result in your DOM being updated. If you don't actually have an `onChange` handler defined using `input.simulate('change')` won't do anything.

So, if your goal is to actually set the value of an input and not trigger an `onChange` handler then you can use JS to manually update the DOM using something like `wrapper.find('#my-input').node.value = 'abc';` however this is circumventing React's render cycle and you'll likely see this value cleared/removed if you do anything to trigger a re-render.

Comment: I am trying to set the value with `input.node.value = "Test"`, and I am getting this error `TypeError: Can't add property value, object is not extensible`.  Any ideas?

Comment: @jhamm Check out my answer below.

Comment: you might need to remove target / value:    
   input.simulate('changeText', '6');

Comment: I also had the issue of: **TypeError: Cannot add property value, object is not extensible**.

What resolved it for me was changing `node.find('#id_name').get(0).value =` to `node.find('#id_name').instance().value =`

Answer (score 25):

I'm using `React 16` and `Enzyme 3.10` over here and this completely worked for me (after trying too many different suggestions out there):

```
wrapper.find("input").instance().value = "abc";
```

Apparently, in previous versions you could use `node` or `getNode()` instead of `instance()`, which were parts of my many previous attempts.

Comment: I used `.node` but Enzyme told me to use `getElement()` but that gave me the react element and not the dom element. Thx for sharing the `instance()` function.

Comment: `typescript` is failing with error: `TS2339: Property value does not exist on type Component<{}, {}>` .
Can you please help?

Comment: @user2133404 Sorry, man...but I have no idea how to tackle this, given I've never worked with Typescript before.

Comment: Typescript needs to know what type of element you're dealing with specifically. In this case `wrapper.find("input").instance<HTMLInputElement>().value = "abc";` would work.

Answer (score 11):

This works for both Enzyme 3 and Enzyme 2:

```
wrapper.find('input').getDOMNode().value = 'new value';
wrapper.find('input').simulate('change');
```

`.getDOMNode()` can be used like `.node` in Enzyme 2 and like `.instance()` in Enzyme 3.

Comment: Enzyme 3.3.x `wrapper.getDOMNode is not a function`. Looks like it's only for `mount` https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/getDOMNode.md

Answer (score 2):

If using TypeScript you can do the following

```
wrapper.find('input').getDOMNode<HTMLInputElement>().value = 'new value';
wrapper.find('input').simulate('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it works for me..

I have change the input text, with value updation.
And **Update my DOM property**.

```
.update()
```

After updating I am checking the button disable property with input mobile number length use cases.

```
const input = MobileNumberComponent.find('input')
input.props().onChange({target: {
   id: 'mobile-no',
   value: '1234567900'
}});
MobileNumberComponent.update()
const Footer = (loginComponent.find('Footer'))
expect(Footer.find('Buttons').props().disabled).equals(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to use Jest's fake time to give my React onChange function time to run and note the new value of the text input. Here's the full test (though, no setup), using React, jest, and enzyme:

```
describe('Modal with text input', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllTimers();
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  it('enter email, get email tag', () => {
    const modal = render();
    let textField = modal.find('input[data-test-id="assignEmailInput"]');
    let tags = modal.find('[className*="spectrum-Tag--removable"]');

    // initial load
    expect(textField.prop('value')).toBe('');
    expect(tags).toHaveLength(3);

    // "write" in the input
    textField.simulate('click');
    textField.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'ashish@example.com' } });

    // enact the writing for jest
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(150);
    modal.update();
    textField = modal.find('input[data-test-id="assignEmailInput"]');
    tags = modal.find('[className*="spectrum-Tag--removable"]');

    expect(textField.prop('value')).toBe('ashish@example.com');
    expect(tags).toHaveLength(3);
    const expected = ['one@example.com', 'example@example.com', 'foo@example.com'];
    tags.forEach((tag, i) => expect(tag.contains(expected[i])).toBe(true));

    // enact the onBlur function that sets tags
    textField.simulate('blur');
    modal.update();
    textField = modal.find('input[data-test-id="assignEmailInput"]');
    tags = modal.find('[className*="spectrum-Tag--removable"]');

    expect(textField.prop('value')).toBe('');
    expect(tags).toHaveLength(4);
    expected.push('ashish@example.com');
    tags.forEach((tag, i) => expect(tag.contains(expected[i])).toBe(true));
  });
});
```