# Enzyme Simulate Error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Im producing the above error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined" When I try to use the simulate method on a range input. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
describe('<USMap />', () => {

const wrapper = mount(<Map />)
const colorControlRed = wrapper.find('#slideRed').children()

test('map changes color', () => {
    colorControlRed.simulate('change', {target: {value: 220}})
});
```

I've also tried

```
colorControlRed.instance().value
```

as mentioned here: [Enzyme - How to access and set <input> value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219772/enzyme-how-to-access-and-set-input-value) . But this does not work either.

I thought the .find maybe wasn't working right, but Im able to console.log the props like below and see the props.

```
console.log(colorControlRed.props())
```

Thanks for your help.

-Boots

Comment: Please provide the code for `<Map>`

Comment: For simulate to work, change needs to be triggered on the actual input that has the onClick handler https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.md. One thing I find super useful for debugging is `console.log(wrapper.debug())`

Comment: Is there something in the click event that looks into an object not present in the test environment that has a match proprety? Maybe somewhere in the event or elsewhere in state or props?